# Android draw graph curve like this with filled area

Tags: android, graph, curve

I would like to draw graph like this (Using Java in Android) :

[image]

I tried to draw the curve using `Bézier` curve but using cubicto and quadto of Path library but had no success in placing the local maxima to the point.

Please help me how this can be acheived?

Comment: If you have not seen then please have look at this https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Yes, I had already watched this. Had no luck in making same graph.